# Как запретить webpack подключать стили к странице

Tags: webpack4

при компиляции он выбирает самый большой файл стилей и подключает его ко ВСЕМ html файлам непонятно зачем. Если файлов стилей нет, то он подключает самый большой JS файл ко ВСЕМ страницам. Как запретить ему подключать что либо по своему собственному усмотрения в html?

Comment: Из коробки webpack не работает с html. Возможно, у вас используется какой-то плагин. Нужно хотя бы увидеть образец вашего конфига и [mcve].

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку:)

Answer (score 1):

вопрос решен. В html webpack plugin нужно было добавить inject:false.